Find an expression for a certain automorphism in $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$
Consider the following automorphisms of the free group $F_n=\langle v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\rangle$:

$\epsilon_i:F_n\to F_n$ defined as $\epsilon_i(v_i)=v_i^{-1}$ and $\epsilon_i(v_j)=v_j$ if $j\neq i$.
$\lambda_{i,j}:F_n\to F_n$ defined as $\lambda_{i,j}(v_i)=v_jv_i$ and $\lambda_{i,j}(v_k)=v_k$ if $k\neq i$.
$\rho_{i,j}:F_n\to F_n$ defined as $\rho_{i,j}(v_i)=v_iv_j$ and $\rho_{i,j}(v_k)=v_k$ if $k\neq i$.

Due to some knwon results about the presentations of $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$ it is known that $\epsilon_2$ can be written as a product of the automorphisms $\epsilon_1,\lambda_{1,2},\lambda_{2,1},\rho_{1,2}$ and $\rho_{2,1}$. I want to find the expression for $\epsilon_2$ in terms of those maps.
Thanks for your help.

Try and get $\sigma: v_1 \mapsto v_2, v_2 \mapsto v_1$ first. Then $\epsilon_2 = \epsilon_1^\sigma$. If I have calculated correctly then $\sigma = \epsilon_1 \rho_{1,2}\rho_{2,1}^{-1}\lambda_{12}$.
